# Heroku - Application Error in angular app

Tags: angularjs, heroku

I've created simple application with angular js and I've tried to push it on Heroku, But I got an application error

[image: Error Image]

My web.js file

```
var gzippo = require('gzippo');
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist"));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

My procfile

```
web: node web.js
```

heroku logs

```
2016-05-10T05:55:48.715598+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-05-10T05:55:51.858299+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-79-generic
2016-05-10T05:55:51.859162+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-05-10T05:55:51.859589+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-05-10T05:55:51.860485+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-05-10T05:55:51.862362+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-10T05:55:51.863641+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-05-10T05:55:51.863780+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-05-10T05:55:51.863909+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-05-10T05:55:51.864030+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-05-10T05:55:51.877146+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-10T05:55:51.877159+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-05-10T05:55:51.877160+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-05-10T05:55:52.902027+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-10T05:55:52.918127+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-10T05:55:52.918127+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-05-10T05:55:54.403387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-05-10T05:55:57.949990+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-79-generic
2016-05-10T05:55:57.950723+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-05-10T05:55:57.951032+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-05-10T05:55:57.951600+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-05-10T05:55:57.952928+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-10T05:55:57.953879+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-05-10T05:55:57.954052+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-05-10T05:55:57.954222+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-05-10T05:55:57.954364+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-05-10T05:55:57.964044+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-10T05:55:57.964055+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-05-10T05:55:57.964056+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-05-10T05:55:58.841657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-10T05:55:58.822853+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-10T05:55:59.805915+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=879d9b51-1dfe-449d-9bdb-a7bbffd6838a fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T05:56:02.548881+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=3db6731b-2d5b-45de-af03-e38a4635731e fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T05:56:24.321302+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=ae8a228c-0974-47ae-b2fa-25936137c626 fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T05:56:27.410436+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=e6eac44f-b06d-4f1b-ac51-25787216cf0a fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T05:57:33.489462+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=4b4faad0-62ca-4dd1-b12f-aea7593a2551 fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T05:57:36.996051+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=291d73ed-120e-41a7-a9e8-4d47be8b9dd7 fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T06:12:07.604036+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 78a1f2d by jihinraju@gmail.com
2016-05-10T06:12:07.604036+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by jihinraju@gmail.com
2016-05-10T06:12:07.803702+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-05-10T06:12:07.803712+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-05-10T06:12:08.050572+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-05-10T06:12:09.054426+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-05-10T06:12:11.436138+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-79-generic
2016-05-10T06:12:11.436680+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-05-10T06:12:11.436933+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-05-10T06:12:11.437361+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-05-10T06:12:11.438637+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-10T06:12:11.439477+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-05-10T06:12:11.439603+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-05-10T06:12:11.439727+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-05-10T06:12:11.439827+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-05-10T06:12:11.447639+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-10T06:12:11.447800+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-05-10T06:12:11.447904+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-05-10T06:12:12.224080+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-10T06:12:12.224080+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-05-10T06:12:12.204522+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-10T06:12:13.737664+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-05-10T06:12:18.464304+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-79-generic
2016-05-10T06:12:18.465113+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-05-10T06:12:18.465540+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-05-10T06:12:18.466610+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-05-10T06:12:18.468574+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-10T06:12:18.470114+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-05-10T06:12:18.470323+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-05-10T06:12:18.470495+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-05-10T06:12:18.470671+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-05-10T06:12:18.487848+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-05-10T06:12:18.487547+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-10T06:12:18.488044+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-05-10T06:12:19.398577+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-10T06:12:19.429487+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-10T06:12:56.439830+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=165171b3-5931-4e90-80c9-449e3b50db00 fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T06:12:58.639148+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=83b50a87-2bc5-4d87-bde2-1a2a5caea658 fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T06:13:01.570815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=9f621b77-1c49-4686-b52b-80d5536c6126 fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T06:13:04.130504+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=1661358c-7b9a-4f7b-b835-1c631d04ff47 fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T06:14:54.260690+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=540998f6-7178-4bc2-923e-dbf3e71a4159 fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T06:14:55.690462+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=a3b645a5-c352-409a-b7f9-3baa61cb3255 fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T06:19:35.666697+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=ccc5da2c-d8e0-42bb-bf41-05bd360e92a5 fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T06:19:53.835985+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=302ce39a-5e56-489a-aa36-56b65c80ab17 fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T06:20:25.558441+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=cb474e67-1046-4c5d-bd2d-2c60bb4248b1 fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-05-10T06:21:28.081318+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=familyarea.herokuapp.com request_id=a4e7c602-ea28-4e20-815e-77511ecc145d fwd="124.124.60.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0):

My Problem Got solved the issue is in procfile extension, I have removed the extention